# Animated Gif or Video into Glb format

Tags: modeling, animation, video, gltf, image-sequence

Is there any method to covert multiple image sequence to animated .glb format? OR can I convert video into glb/gltf format? I want to play a video in WebAR using MindAR. Anyone can help me to do this. Thanks